# Размер текста в процентном соотношении от default

Tags: android, шрифты

подскажите, есть ли возможность задавать размер шрифта в процентном соотношении от шрифта по умолчанию. Для применения на различных устройствах. Допустим на устройстве с маленьким размером экрана это будет 100% размер шрифта(т.е. дефолтный), а на large 200% или это всё надо фиксировано прописывать в ресурсах и использовать потом уже фиксированный размер текста?

Comment: чтобы размер текста увеличивался пропорциорально экрану, указывайте его размер в значениях dp (а не sp). например `android:textSize = 24dp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос. К примеру. На маленьком экране у вас кнопка или текст на половину экрана, и на большом, кнопка или текст на половину экрана. То вы просто указываете размер кнопки в DP или текст в SP. И в любом варианте размеры будут такие же, как и в том, в котором вы делали.

Comment: Наверное я как-то не правильно сформулировал вопрос. Попробую чуть яснее его изложить. У меня есть допустим стандартный размер экрана. На нём я задаю жестко размер шрифта допустим 20 sp. После этого, я хочу, чтобы на большом экране у меня этот текст выглядел так же. Т.е. экран увеличился и размер текста должен тоже увеличиться допустим в 1.5 раза. и вопрос в том, можно как-то в процентном соотношении это сделать или необходимо просто жестко задать размеры шрифтов и потом использовать их для разных экранов.

Comment: Поздно отвечаю, но я думаю, вам уже ответили выше. Указывайте размер в dp.